# Is it allowed to shift parts of an interface between two programs to the constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, software-design

I have a class in a different WPF project. I have access to this class and am allowed to edit it. Now I have another WPF project and the main window should be opened inside the class of the different WPF project. The class of the different project provides many information. Based on these information the new project has to made decisions according to it's working style. 
My idea was to make an interface with some getter methods and implement it in the target class. When I would generate a new instance of the main window, this interface would be used as the only parameter.

The problem is the diversity of different working styles is very large. As a result I would have to make many if statements in the constructor to find out the working style of my application.

Is it a good practice to remove parts of the interface an put it into the constructor of the called main window as parameters? Therefore I would be able to code a few more constructors, based on the parameters. As a result I wouldn't have that many conditions and checks.

What would be the better, right (and more accepted) approach? 
Is there any principle which explains that?

Here is a small code example of an:

```
public interface IToImplement {
     int GetIndex();
     int GetOldIndex();
     string GetMainObjectAsList();
     string GetDocPath();
     string GetDocName();
}
```

Here is my class where I want to show the other wpf application:

```
public class MasterClass : IToImplement {
     ...
     ...

     private void StartOtherApp() {
          MainWindow window = null;
          if (something)
               window = new MainWindow(this);
          else if (anything)
               window = new MainWindow(this, path);
          else
               window = new MainWindow(this, path, name);

          window.ShowDialog();
     }
}
```

Those Statements aren't changable.

Last my MainWindow class in my other project:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
     public MainWindow() {
          InitializeComponent();
     }

     public MainWindow(IToImplement i) {
     }

     public MainWindow(IToImplement i, string path) {
     }

     public MainWindow(IToImplement i, string path, string name) {
     }
}
```

The parameters path and name are taken from the interface functions GetDocPath() and GetDocName(). Therefore these two functions should be removed from my implemented interface and should be shifted as parameters into the constructor like in the code example above. Otherwise I had to implement three if statement in my constructor with one parameter.

Comment: Please provide some code background. Having many `if`s breaks the Open-Closed Principle of SOLID. Having a class that "provides many information" breaks the Single Responsibility Principle of SOLID.

Comment: @dymanoid Thank you for your advice. I provided some code.